# How to show the space is totally bounded?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, metric-spaces

the space the Real line with bounded metric (i.e. d/(1+d), d: euclidean)

we know that totally boundedness means that there exists a finite epsilon-net.
we first approached to question by directly try to find finitely many points s.t. their metric balls cover the space. then, tried , by contradiction, but failure.

Comment: Hint: is it complete?

Comment: yes. since R with |.| is complete and |.| > bounded metric. but could not get the hint.

Comment: Doesn't follow that easily. The bounded metric could have more Cauchy sequences than the Euclidean. That aside, a complete metric space is totally bounded if and only if it is - what?

Comment: i am not sure. but a good candidate will be "bounded"

Comment: No, something stronger.

Comment: so, is it easier to show the space is compact ?

Comment: i am lost. gonna sleep. appreciate any hints.

Comment: @user104078: The space is **not** compact, since it’s homeomorphic to $\Bbb R$. Thus, if it’s complete, it cannot be totally bounded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT: Let $d_b$ be the bounded metric, so that $$d_b(x,y)=\frac{|x-y|}{1+|x-y|}$$ for all $x,y\in\Bbb R$. Suppose that $m,n\in\Bbb Z$ and $m\ne n$; then $d_b(m,n)\ge\ldots\;$?